# how to display spaces in big numbers using smarty?

Tags: numbers, smarty

i have number 123456 in my variable.

how to display it like 123 456  in smarty ?

so i want something like this

1 000

1 000 000

...

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use: `{$number|number_format}`

See also http://smarty.incutio.com/?page=commify if you need to retain any digits after a decimal point.